# mysql problem left join and from_unixtime

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I have this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) cnt, a.auther_id
    FROM `posts` a 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON a.auther_id = u.id
    GROUP BY a.auther_id
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    LIMIT 20
```

It works fine, but now I want select posts from within the last day. I tried to use

```
    WHERE from_unixtime(post_time) >= SUBDATE(NOW(),1)
```

but it didn't work. Any one have idea why?

Comment: How, precisely, didn't it work? Always describe the what you expect and what you get, including any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(post_time) >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```